# What is the size limitation of xml doc and binary doc in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

The MongoDB size limitation of a json document is 16MB.

Does MarkLogic have a similar limitation for XML and Binary docs?

How does MarkLogic ingest a large binary file such as a video or Excel spreadsheet that is greater than 2MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic makes a distinction between files it can index, and files it can't. A bit much to go into full detail, but here an attempt to a reasonably short overview:

Binary files can't be indexed directly, though you can extract text and metadata with it for many formats. There are three ways of storing those binaries:

1. Inside the database
2. As so-called managed external binaries
3. As unmanaged external binaries

There is a large-binary threshold that automatically distinguishes between 1 and 2 at insert into the database. By default this threshold is set to 1 Mb. You don't really notice this difference normally though, you access both just the same way. I have so far not seen an upper limit to the size of managed external binaries, and if there are, they are likely imposed by the underlying filesystem format or OS. I could ingest a 1 Gb zip, and pull it out again without much trouble, and very fast as well on local disks. Managed large binaries are included in backups to my knowledge.

Unmanaged external binaries is like storing them separately. You can do that from outside MarkLogic, but also from inside. MarkLogic allows writing and reading files to locations on disk. There files are obviously not included in backups, and another downside is that you cannot associate so-called properties with them, that are stored within MarkLogic database, and can be indexed as well. Managed external binaries do allow that. I'm not aware of particular restrictions to such unmanaged binaries.

MarkLogic 7 is capable of full-text search on text and XML documents. It also support many other indexes on XML documents. MarkLogic 7 allows storing JSON as a specific XML structure that can be indexed as well. MarkLogic 8 will store and index JSON documents natively. There is no fixed limit to the sizes of such documents, but it depends on how they are processed, how they are stored, and what memory settings have been applied.

To put it short, MarkLogic works with fragments, and a fragment needs to fit into a so-called in-memory page. I believe it is directly related to the in memory tree size setting on databases, which defaults to 128 Mb on my personal laptop with 16 Gb physical memory. These pages are used for all handling of content where it needs to actually access the content. This could be for parsing and traversing XML to evaluate an XPath, but could also be a string replace on a text document, or unzipping a zip to extract and store its individual files within the database.

You can increase memory setting to fit your needs. But mind though, MarkLogic will often be processing requests and tasks in parallel. Keep in mind that if all those requests and tasks will be claiming pages of large size, you will need a lot of memory!

If you really want to know all the details, I recommend reading [Inside MarkLogic Server](http://developer.marklogic.com/inside-marklogic) by Jason Hunter
HTH!

Comment: MarkLogic Dev, Mike Blakeley, posted more detail here. [http://markmail.org/message/kgijddmcofhxzvgv](http://markmail.org/message/kgijddmcofhxzvgv)

This is the doc mentioned in Mike’s response.

[https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/formats#id_33599](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/formats#id_33599)

_The maximum size of a single XML fragment is 128 MB for 32-bit machines, 512 MB for 64-bit machines._

Comment: Yes, very good remarks. I guess I kind of looked at the question slightly differently..